# What APIs are available to access my Office 365 Auth Token?

Tags: node.js, authentication, outlook, office365

I'm developing an addin for Outlook and there is a library available within the addin that allows me to access the auth token for the user logged in.

The specific code is:

```
Office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync((result) => {
    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        console.error(`Token retrieval failed with message: ${result.error.message}`);
    }
    callback(result.value);
});
```

The documentation can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-rest-api

However, I'm looking to get my auth token from outside of the addin. I have been searching for an API that allows me to send my username/password and get the auth token, but I can not find any such thing.

How can I get my auth token without creating a web crawler for https://outlook.office.com/?

Comment: The `getUserIdentityTokenAsync` function gets the OIDC `id_token` - [the identity-token **is not** an auth-token](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/id-tokens). In fact the name "identity token" is really a misnomer in my opinion: the `id_token` is just a big JSON dictionary of user claims and profile settings (more-or-less). You cannot use an `id_token` to authenticate a client nor use it to gain access to any services.

Comment: "I have been searching for an API that allows me to send my username/password and get the auth token, but I can not find any such thing." - **such a thing does not exist** because it's very, very, insecure. OIDC is built around not having to use passwords at all - instead OIDC uses delegated and `scope`-specific time-limited `access_token` bearer-tokens (and some other related stuff I won't go into detail into).

Comment: @Dai You are correct, I was wrong about getting the auth token. However, is there a way I can get a users identity token outside of the addin?

Comment: What do you mean by "outside of the addin"? That's _very_ open-ended.... I certainly can't get any Office 365 `id_token` from Notepad or Photoshop....

Answer (score 0):

Possible choices are described in depth in the [Authentication options in Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/authentication) article.

1. Single sign-on access tokens provide a seamless way for your add-in to authenticate and obtain access tokens to call the Microsoft Graph API. This capability reduces friction since the user is not required to enter their credentials.
2. Exchange user identity tokens provide a way for your add-in to establish the identity of the user. By verifying the user's identity, you can then perform a one-time authentication into your back-end system, then accept the user identity token as an authorization for future requests.
3. Add-ins can also access third-party services that support OAuth2 for authorization. Using this method, your add-in prompts the user to sign-in to the service either by using the `displayDialogAsync` method to initialize the `OAuth2` flow, or by using the `office-js-helpers` library to the `OAuth2` Implicit flow.